# Sorting results in php before being displayed

Tags: php, sorting

Let me start by saying that I am very new to PHP and doing what I can. That said, feel free to  criticize my code, but know that I am already aware.

Okay, all of this code is working right now. I just need to figure out why I cannot get it to sort by 'price' before displaying the results. The code below is where I believe the sorting should happen.

```
<?php 
$group = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'product_categories', '', ', ', '' );
$group = strip_tags($group);
$index = 'group';
foreach ($results as $tire) {
if ($tire->group == $group) { 
    if($tire->sort6 == "C" || $tire->sort6 == "D" || $tire->sort6 == "E" || $tire->sort6 == "F"){
            $test = (string) $tire->description;
            $tiresize = preg_split('/ /', $test);
            $warranty = substr($test,-3,2);
            if (!is_numeric($warranty))
                $warranty = "Please contact for more information.";
            else if ($warranty == 00)
                $warranty = "No mileage warranty";
            else
                $warranty = $warranty.",000 mile warranty";

        echo '<strong>'.'<font size="4" color="#000">'.'$'.number_format($tire->price, 2).'</font>'.'</strong>'.' - '.$tiresize[0].' '.$tire->sort6.' - '.$warranty.'<br/>';

    }else{
            $test = (string) $tire->description;
            $tiresize = preg_split('/ /', $test);
            $warranty = substr($test,-3,2);
            if (!is_numeric($warranty))
                $warranty = "Please contact for more information.";
            else if ($warranty == 00)
                $warranty = "No mileage warranty";
            else
                $warranty = $warranty.",000 mile warranty";

        //echo '<strong>'.'<font size="4" color="#000">'.'$'.number_format($price_string, 2).'</font>'.'</strong>'.' - '.'P'.$tiresize[0].' '.$tire->sort4.$tire->sort5.' - '.$warranty.'<br/>';

        echo '<strong>'.'<font size="4" color="#000">'.'$'.number_format($tire->price, 2).'</font>'.'</strong>'.' - '.'P'.$tiresize[0].' '.$tire->sort4.$tire->sort5.' - '.$warranty.'<br/>';

    }
    }  
    } 

?>
```

This is a link to where you can see the full code:
http://pastie.org/8357831

Comment: what sorting? there's no sorting whatsoever in that code...

Comment: You are right there is not. I was saying that I think that is where the sorting should go, but it is not there. I do not know how I would sort by a key in this area. In my full code link, there are some ORDER BY that I have tried.